# Slow home screen load, applications restarting

Tags: 4.4-kitkat, performance, motorola-moto-g

The problem has a few symptoms. 1) Whenever I return to the home screen it takes a few seconds to redraw. 2) Most applications restart when I switch back and forth between them. 3) If I go to the Running Apps menu many of the apps are listed as "Restarting". 4) Some background applications quit unexpectedly (like playing music in the background).

This is on a Moto G Android v4.4.4. The phone is a few months old and the problem appeared about a month ago. At all times free RAM is ~200 MB out of 870 MB.

Could anyone give me some hints of what is going on? The Internet tells me to factory reset my phone, but that's a bit of the "Reformat your C:" of the PC world back in the day.

Comment: Have you changed any of the developer settings in the main settings app? Do you remember installing any apps around the time the problem started?

Comment: I don't even have developer settings enabled and the phone is not rooted. The only two apps that I remember installing around that time are "CatLog" and "Super-Bright LED Torch". I have since removed both.